# AS2 on key press change frame of symbol

Tags: flash, actionscript, frame

I have ball converted to symbol (movie clip) with 2 frames (blue and red ball). I want when left arrow is pressed, frame inside ball change to frame 1 and if i press right arrow, frame inside ball change to 2. Ball symbol name is "ball". I am really new with flash and AS2, so sorry if i look like noob :)

Here is what i've tried:

```
on(keyPress "37"){
    ball.gotoAndStop(1);
}
on(keyPress "39"){
    ball.gotoAndStop(2);
}
```

I placed it in actionscript panel of ball.

key for Left Arrow is 37
key for Right Arrow is 39

Answer (score 0):

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00001133.html

Adobe covers this in their docs.

You use a Key.addListener(myListener) and then you can check for key codes 37 and 39.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, i we found answer long time ago by myself. Code doesn't work because movieclip ball doesn't have INSTANCE NAME "ball" (because of ball.gotoAndStop).